# Como liberar acesso a pasta Public

Tags: php, htaccess

Olá, estou tentando utilizar htaccess para fazer redirecionamento em um projeto, mas tenho encontrado um problema em relação ao acesso a minha pasta Public, onde ficam minhas assets.

Abaixo segue meu `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteCond Public/$1 -F
    RewriteRule (.+) Public/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond $0 !^(index\.php|Public/)

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?key=$1 [QSA]
</IfModule>
```

O problema que acontece é o seguinte:

quando faço a chamada na minha masterpage `<script src="Public/css/styles.css">`
ele joga o valor `Public/css/styles.css` para a `index.php?key=$1`...

Eu precisava que acessasse a pasta Public/css e fizerem a chamada normal do css/js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A primeira regra já faz isso não precisa da `RewriteCond Public...`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?key=$1 [L,QSA]
```

---

Esse outro jeito deve fazer o que você quer mas não me agrada muito

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg|css|js|swf)$ /<public>/$1.$2 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Ai só mudar o  pela pasta raiz onde ta os assets no caso acho que /$1.$2

Comment: Então, não está fazendo, porque quando eu estou em por exemplo site.com/usuarios/listar os meus src="public/assets" tentam acessar site.com/usuarios/public

Comment: coloca o caminho absoluto no link /public/assets

Comment: não lembro onde eu havia lido a respeito, mas dizia que utilizar absolute paths não era uma boa prática

Comment: não é uma boa prática sua aplicação não funcionar

Comment: esse é um ponto bem interessante também